# Deleting files older than 10 days in wildcard directory loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would like to delete old files from multiple directories but there is a wild card for one of the path attributes. So I'm trying to loop through each of those directories without specifying each one. I think I'm almost there but I'm not sure how to cd into the specific directory to delete the relevant files.

```
#! /bin/bash

DELETE_SEARCH_DIR=/apps/super/userprojects/elasticsearch/v131/node*/elasticsearch-1.3.1/logs/

    for entry in `ls $DELETE_SEARCH_DIR`; do
      find $path -name "*super*"  -type f -mtime +10 -print -delete
      #find . -type f -name $entry -exec rm -f {} \;
    done
```

Any ideas on how to get into the specific directory and apply the delete?

Comment: [Don't loop over files with `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Especially if you are just going to use `find` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` can search in multiple directories.  You can do it like this:

```bash
DELETE_SEARCH_DIR=/apps/super/userprojects/elasticsearch/v131/node*/elasticsearch-1.3.1/logs
find $DELETE_SEARCH_DIR -type f -name '*super*' -mtime +10 -print -delete
```

Comment: does find go into subdirectories